# Use of 'be' in English

Tags: passive-voice

I am a learner of English and I have some doubts about '**be**'. Please check the sentences and help me to understand it(be).

What are differences between these sentences. I meant to ask why we should use '**be**' here.

> There are a few restrictions that need to be kept in mind.
>
> **VS**
>
> There are a few restrictions that need to keep in mind.

Let me also share what I understand by it(**be**) and when I use it normally, but I am not sure that I have been using it perfectly so I just wanted to make it more clear.

We use **be** to complete a sentence for a non-living thing as a non-living thing cannot be done itself. It needs someone's help to complete the action.

Answer (score 4):

Snailplane put you on the right track by inserting the proper tag: "passive-voice" is the key idea.

We have two ideas :
 1. There are a few restrictions.
 2. We need to keep these restrictions in mind.

To join these two ideas into one sentence we have two solutions:

#### Using a relative clause:

> There are a few restrictions that we need to keep in mind.

"that" is a relative pronoun, object of "keep in mind", it can be omitted:

> There are a few restrictions we need to keep in mind.

#### Using the passive voice:

> There are a few restrictions that need to be kept in mind.

"Be" is part of the passive voice (be+past participle of the verb).

Using the passive voice here saves us from expressing the agent ("we") that is obvious and general here.

> There are a few restrictions that need to be kept in mind (by us/people).

would be correct but clumsy. If necessity arose to express it than the construction with the relative clause would be preferred.

Comment: You have not arrived at his second sentence. Notice that there is no *we*, no *be* and *keep* is in the present tense.

Comment: @Graduate: as I say in my answer his second is not correct because "need" has no subject. I rectified his second sentence in my answer.

Comment: @Laure Thank you so much. Let me ask you one more question about 'be'. Why are we using 'be' here (It could be done)?

Comment: @user62015. "It could be done." is a sentence in the passive voice. See what I wrote in my answer *"Be" is part of the passive voice (be+past participle of the verb).* [This page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv65.shtml)  might help you understanding the passive voice.